# Parsing XML response with Rails 4 and Savon 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, savon

I´m using Rails and Savon 2 to get data from a SOAP Webservice.

This is the code:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://www.webservicex.net/periodictable.asmx?WSDL", 
                      log_level: :debug,
                      pretty_print_xml: true)
    message = {'ElementName' => 'Zinc'}
    response = client.call(:get_element_symbol, message: message)
    logger.debug "Body=" + response.body.to_s 
    symbol = response.to_hash[:get_element_symbol_response][:get_element_symbol_result][:NewDataDet][:Table][:Symbol]
```

The request is ok and I´m getting the data in the response:

```
Body={:get_element_symbol_response=>{:get_element_symbol_result=>"<NewDataSet>\n  <Table>\n    <Symbol>Zn</Symbol>\n  </Table>\n</NewDataSet>", :@xmlns=>"http://www.webserviceX.NET"}}
```

But now, I don´t know how to parse this response correctly to get the "Symbol".

I´m getting this error:

```
`TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):`
```

**UPDATE:**

If I do:

```
symbol = response.to_hash[:get_element_symbol_response][:get_element_symbol_result]
logger.debug "Symbol=" + symbol.inspect
```

I get this: Symbol=`"<NewDataSet>\n  <Table>\n    <Symbol>Zn</Symbol>\n  </Table>\n</NewDataSet>"`

I think the error is that I´m trying to get Symbol in hash mode, and it is not. But how can I get the symbol? I can´t believe I have to parse the string manually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html) to parse XML text:

```
require 'nokogiri'

text = response.body[:get_element_symbol_response][:get_element_symbol_result]

Nokogiri::XML(text).css('Symbol').text # => Zn
# or
Nokogiri::XML(text).xpath('//NewDataSet/Table/Symbol').text # => Zn
```

Comment: Isn´t there any other more like json or hash style?

Comment: @Rober you could use `Nokogiri::Slop` for that
check out their documentation, quite funny too